# svcutil giving errors when trying to create proxy from complex wsdl

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am working on a WSDL published by standards organization (IHE). It is very complex with over 60 XSDs included in it for data types.

When I try to use svcutil to generate client proxy, I am getting the following error

***Warning: The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/' was not handled.***

XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:ihe:iti:pixv3:2007']/wsdl:binding[@name='PIXManager_Binding_Soap12']/wsdl:operation[@name='PIXManager_PRPA_IN201304UV02']/wsdl:output*

If required, I can post the wsdl and associated files.

Thanks

Comment: I have added the same question on MSDN forum with more details         http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5de51bb8-926c-4f07-99f8-f7585d002ce9

Answer (score 0):

You might get more responses if you put a link up to the wsdl you're tying to use to build your proxy. My guess is there is namespace definition problem. I did find someone else with a similar problem and a solution for it posted at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/47ce5fa0-8382-499b-acd2-f4bba48359df/) MSDN forum entry.

Comment: I do not have a link that I can share, but I could post the wsdl if you think that helps. You can also get the wsdl here ftp://ftp.ihe.net/TF_Implementation_Material/ITI/packages/PIXV3.Support.Materials.v5.zip . I looked at the link. It is related but I have already overcome that particular error. This is next in line :). I am able to generate the files despite the warnings but the files are incomplete.

Comment: I'll see what I can make of it tomorrow. Thanks for the link!